# Performance of C++ Union-Find solution is strangely poor

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, union-find

**[Problem Summary (USACO Gold 3 February 2016](http://usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=623))**

> Given a rectangular coordinate plane of dimensions `(A,B)`, there are `N` vertical fences, and `M` horizontal fences. Clearly, the intersection of these fences within the larger rectangle creates `(n+1)(m+1)` regions.
>
> Given `A,B,N,M`, the x-coordinates of the `N` vertical fences and the y coordinates of the `M` horizontal fences, find the minimum amount of fence to remove to create a minimum spanning tree (connect all regions). In order to remove a fence and thus union two adjacent regions, the entire length of fence between them must be removed.

**[Solution](http://usaco.org/current/data/sol_fencedin_gold_feb16.html)**

This is clearly a disjoint-set union problem (union-find/Kruskals), but the tricky part is building the edge-list and tree to union. Each edge is weighted by the length of fence between the two nodes that it connects.

Here is a quick outline of the code below:

1. Read in x,y coords of vertical, horizontal fences (also add 0,0,A,B as "fences")
2. For each intersection of the fences (some special cases at ends), add the left-facing and up-facing edges to edge list, and additionally add the region between the two edges as a node to the union-find tree.
3. Run Kruskals, keeping track of distance.

This is an O(ElogV) algorithm, which should be more than fast enough since N and M are less than 2000. Note that the given solution (linked above) is fast enough, where this takes to long (failure) for the last 4/10 test cases.

[Download Test Cases (10)](http://usaco.org/current/data/fencedin_gold_feb16.zip)

Where is the performance bottleneck? How can this be improved?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

#define ll long long

using namespace std;

const string PROJ_NAME = "fencedin";

struct edge {
    ll dist;
    int start;
    int finish;
    bool operator< (const edge &rhs) const { return dist < rhs.dist || (!(rhs.dist < dist) && start < rhs.start) || (!(rhs.start < start) && finish < rhs.finish); }
};

struct uf_node {
    int parent;
    int level;
};

ll A, B;
int N, M;
set<edge> edge_list;
vector<uf_node> tree;

void make_edge_list(ifstream &fin){
    fin >> A >> B >> N >> M;

    vector<int> vert(N+2);
    vert[0] = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i<=N; i++) fin >> vert[i];
    vert[N+1] = A;
    N++;

    vector<int> hori(M+2);
    hori[0] = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i<=M; i++) fin >> hori[i];
    hori[M+1] = B;
    M++;

    sort(vert.begin(), vert.end());
    sort(hori.begin(), hori.end());

    tree.resize(N*M);
    for(int i = 1; i<=N; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j<=M; j++){
            int curr = (i-1)*M+(j-1);

            //Add node to DSU tree
            uf_node n = {.parent = curr, .level = 0};
            tree[curr] = n;

            //Add leftward edge if not at bottom
            if(i != N){
                edge left = {.dist = hori[j]-hori[j-1], .start=curr, .finish=curr+M};
                edge_list.insert(left);
            }

            //Add upward edge if not at right
            if(j != M){
                edge up = {.dist = vert[i]-vert[i-1], .start=curr, .finish=curr+1};
                edge_list.insert(up);
            }
        }
    }
}

int find_par(int i) {
    if(i != tree[i].parent) {
        tree[i].parent = find_par(tree[i].parent);
    }
    return tree[i].parent;
}

void do_union(int i, int j) {
    int r = find_par(i);
    int s = find_par(j);
    if(r == s) return;
    else if (tree[r].level > tree[s].level) {
        tree[r].parent = s;
    } else if (tree[s].level > tree[r].level) {
        tree[s].parent = r;
    } else {
        tree[r].parent = s;
        tree[r].level += 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    ifstream fin (PROJ_NAME + ".in");
    ofstream fout (PROJ_NAME + ".out");

    make_edge_list(fin);

    int total_dist = 0;
    for(edge e: edge_list){
        if(find_par(e.start) != find_par(e.finish)){
            do_union(e.start, e.finish);
            total_dist += e.dist;
        }
    }

    fout << total_dist << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `tree[r].level > tree[r].level` - a typo?

Comment: @vnp Edited, did not fix problem. Good catch.

Comment: Should the `if` in `find_par` be `if (i == tree[i].parent)`?

Comment: No, as long as the parent is not itself (not a root) continue iterating.

Comment: Do you have any more input cases to test with than the example on the linked website? That particular one runs in less time than the profiler has to sample the program!

Comment: @user1118321 Yes: http://usaco.org/current/data/fencedin_gold_feb16.zip (added as link in OP)

Comment: The union-find algorithm should be implemented with a single array (vector). When traversing the tree, flatten it. You want each node to directly link to the parent node at all times. If I have time tonight I'll share my implementation of an efficient union-find class.

Comment: I believe my implementation does that (see the find function). It requires only a list of edges for Kruskals and a vector for union find.

Comment: @EvanWeissburg: Yes, it does, I didn't notice that at first, sorry. But then why do you keep the `level`? If the forest is flat, with each node directly pointing at its root, they all have a level of 0 or 1. It doesn't matter which one you pick as the root. Checking the level is just wasting time... A `vector<int>` would improve data locality as well (with the data being half the size, there'll be fewer cache misses).

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a really interesting problem! Here are some things I noticed about your implementation.

## Performance

Looking at a profile of your code (compiled with llvm on macOS High Sierra with Xcode 9.2), it looks like the majority of time is spent in these 3 places:

- 85% in `make_edge_list()`, particularly the 2 calls to `set::insert()`
- 7% in `find_par()`
- 7% in `std::tree::iterator::operator++()` (so incrementing an iterator on your edge list, I believe)

What this means, I think, is that `std::set` is maybe not the best choice of container in this case. Since you can't preallocate space for items in a `set` like you can with a `vector` or `array`, it has to do the allocations on-the-fly, which can hamper performance. Also, choosing where to insert things seems to be part of the time sink of `insert()` as well. With a `vector` you can preallocate memory, and then `push_back()` just adds it to the end. It's not clear what you're getting by using a `set` here, so I say ditch it. The linked solution uses only a single `vector` and a static array of ~2000 x 2000 elements and does some sorting. So that might be a winning strategy here.

## Naming

Macros have all sorts of problems. But even when you manage to write a macro that won't have any of those problems, as you did here, if there's a better way, you should use it. (For example, what if someone modifying this code makes a variable named `ll` or writes a string with the word "all" in it?) If you want your own shorter name for `long long`, then do:

```
using ll = long long;
```

or at the very least:

```
typedef long long ll;
```

But really - too lazy to type `long long`? Just type it out. It's a well-known type.

I'm not a fan of 1-letter variable names in most cases. The values `A` and `B` are the dimensions. I'd name them `width` and `height`. `N` and `M` are the number of vertical and horizontal fences, so why not name them `num_vert_fences` and `num_horz_fences`? Or even just `rows` and `columns`?

## Avoid `using namespace std`

You should really [avoid using `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) for all the reasons pointed out there.

## Globals

The use of globals made it hard to read your code. Down in `do_union()`, I had to scroll all the way back up to the top of the file to see what type `tree` was. You should define these variables in `main()` and pass them to the functions that use them. That will make it much easier to understand the flow of the program and avoid problems where some function changes a variable you didn't pass it while you're using the same variable in another function.

I mentioned in my comment that the globals screwed up my performance analysis. This is a great example of the unintended consequences of globals. Because the code was running too fast to analyze, I took `main()`, renamed it `main2()`, and then wrote a new `main()` to simply call it 100 times in a loop. But because the `tree` and `edge_list` are global, they didn't get cleared out when `main2()` exited as they would have if they had been local. So that resulted in the numbers of my analysis being incorrect because the containers can have different characteristics when there are many more items in them than when there are fewer. Lesson learned. I should have made the variables local before running my performance test.

## Be Careful with Less-Well-Known Tools

I really like this method of initializing the members of a `struct` or `union`:

```
uf_node n = {.parent = curr, .level = 0};
```

I recently started using it and coworkers with many years of experience have been expressing surprise and concern over it! So just know that you might confuse some readers with it. It's the type of thing I'd like to see catch on, though, as it improves readability once you understand it.

Comment: Geometric scientific applications make wide use of [quad-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) (2D) and [oct-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) (3D) for improved insertion and search times. [Here is an explanation of these structures](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter37.html) for a GPU oriented application (the figures in the article help to understand how they work).

Comment: This is code for a (past) programming competition, some time counts especially with long long. Thanks for the advice, I'll test out the optimizations tonight.

Comment: Actually, I screwed up the performance analysis because of the globals. I'll re-run it tonight and post an update. Sorry about that. It just occurred to me this morning.

Comment: OK, I've redone it. It's not drastically different, in that the same functions are implicated. (Not surprising, since the code is so small.) But the amounts are pretty different. 85% vs 56% for the highest cost function.

Comment: It's actually still too slow even when using a preallocated vector -- have you looked at the linked solution in the OP? Maybe that will give you more of a hint than it gave me about why my solution is too slow. I added my updated code to the OP as well.

Comment: A quick profile run shows that in the new code sorting the `vector` is taking up 77% of the time, `find_par()` is taking up 12% of the time, and calls to `push_back()` are taking up about 9% of the time. Have you entered the solution into the tester to see if it passes. Yours runs 100x in under a second on my machine, so it doesn't seem too bad. I haven't had time to assess the given solution.

Comment: @EvanWeissburg: sorting is your largest cost, maybe you need to avoid sorting an array with so many duplicate values. If all fences along a column have the same length, and the fences along a row have the same length, maybe you only need to sort the column widths and row widths separately, then compose your edge list. And maybe the edge list can be implied, you might not even need to store it...